# a rather complicated case in filtering dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

I have a `dictionary` such as:

```
{2:'r', 4:'y', 5:'u', 7:'y', 13:'r', 17:'y'}
```

and I want a list: for every duplicated `value` the first `key` with that `value` . so in this example I want

```
[2, 4]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: we should also have more context here - after python 3.7, dictionaries are ordered by order of entry. are you only dealing with hand-coded dicts where you know the order of entry?

Comment: keys are integers and are ordered in ascending order @shortorian

Comment: I could only filter non-duplicated values by constructing a counting dictionaty. @Tuqay

Answer (score 1):

We can use a new dictionary to reverse k and v:

```
d = {2:'r', 4:'y', 5:'u', 7:'y', 13:'r', 17:'y'}
new_dict = {}
for k,v in d.items():
    new_dict[v] = new_dict.get(v, []) + [k]
```

Now we have a new dictionary whose keys are values of the original dictionary and values are lists containing keys from the original dictionary whose values are now the key of the new dictionary. Now we have to check if there are more than 1 element in values:

```
duplicates = []
for k,v in new_dict.items():
    if len(v)>1:
        duplicates.append(v[0])
```